# Does the volume with cross sections perpendicular to $x$-axis equal the cross sections perpendicular to $y$-axis?

Tags: calculus, volume

I've been working on this problem: Find the volume of the solid whose base is the region bounded between the curve $y=x^2$ and the $x$-axis from $x=0$ to $x=2$ and whose cross sections taken perpendicular to the $x$-axis are squares. $$\int_0^2 (x^2)^2 dx = \frac{32}5,$$ but when I tried to take the cross section perpendicular to the $y$-axis with squares I get $$\int_0^4 (2-\sqrt{y})^2 dy = \frac{8}3.$$ Shouldn't both those areas be equal? Aren't I covering the same amount of area in both integrals? What am I doing wrong? Or they shouldn't be equal? Why not? Thanks!

Comment: You're taking two completely different sets of squares -- one in vertical planes, the other in horizontal planes. What on earth makes you think that these two sets of squares describe the same volume?

Comment: oh i see i guess I'm having trouble visualizing it. So my calculations are correct then? The areas SHOULDN'T be equal.

Comment: The area between the curves is the same. The area of the squares is not. For example, with respect to x there is one cross-section which has a length of 4, yet the maximum cross-sectional length with respect to y is 2.

Comment: Yes, your calculations are correct as verified by Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: that makes sense, thank you so much! I kept thinking i was doing something wrong.

Comment: If you can sketch a few of the squares from an oblique view, you may start to get some idea of how different the three-dimensional shapes are depending on which axis the squares are perpendicular to. It could be a useful exercise. But whether you can visualize it or not, your integrals are correctly set up (as well as correctly computed) and therefore demonstrate that the two solid figures are different (since they have different volumes).